# JSON date format changes by itself

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, date

I have a jquery ui calendar picker widget that returns me a date in GMT-5, then I take this javascript date object, and I send it to my server with $.ajax({}) as a dataType: "json". The value gets automatically transformed in Zulu time (ex: 2012-02-08T08:00:00.000Z is sent).

How can I stop this auto convertion so my date stays in GMT-5?

How I grab the date:

```
var basicStartDate = $("#datepicker").datepicker( "getDate" );
        basicStartDate.setMinutes($('#timepickerStart').datetimepicker('getDate').getMinutes());
        basicStartDate.setHours($('#timepickerStart').datetimepicker('getDate').getHours());
```

How I POST the data:

```
 $.ajax({
                url: '/theUrl',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(object),
                contentType: "application/json",
                cache: false,
                timeout: 5000,
                complete: function() {
                    //called when complete


                },

                success: function(data) {


                },

                error: function() {

                },
            });
```

Thanks

Comment: Is the date picker returning an instance of the `Date` object?

Comment: Exactly how are you doing the ajax setup?

Comment: what is your server side technology?

Comment: I am using node.js with a mongodb database using the mongoose module.

Answer (score 2):

[JSON has no "date" format](http://markembling.info/2011/07/json-date-time), you need to handle stringifying and parsing carefully. Meaning that if it looks like your dates have an unwanted offset, predict it and format accordingly.